# Applied head js but script doesnt execute

Tags: javascript, head.js

I am just using headjs for my website but the problem is the files are loaded, but they doesnt execute.

Here is my code in the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/head.js"></script>
<script>
head.js(
"js/jquery.js",
"js/fadetext.js",
"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js",
"css/slider/responsiveslides.min.js"
);
</script>
```

My slideshow is not working for which i used jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js rest all scripts i working??? should I also use headjs for inline js like dis

```
<script>
// You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
$(function () {

  // Slideshow 1
  $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    pager: true,
    nav: true,
    speed: 600,
    maxwidth: 1920,
    namespace: "centered-btns"
  });

  // Slideshow 2
  $("#slider2").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    pager: true,
    nav: true,
    speed: 600,
    maxwidth: 1920,
    namespace: "transparent-btns"
  });

  // Slideshow 3
  $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 600,
    maxwidth: 1920,
    namespace: "large-btns"
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling a callback after the resources have finished loading

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/head.js"></script>
<script>
    function initSliders() {
          // Slideshow 1
          $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
            auto: true,
            pager: true,
            nav: true,
            speed: 600,
            maxwidth: 1920,
            namespace: "centered-btns"
          });

          // Slideshow 2
          $("#slider2").responsiveSlides({
            auto: true,
            pager: true,
            nav: true,
            speed: 600,
            maxwidth: 1920,
            namespace: "transparent-btns"
          });

          // Slideshow 3
          $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
            auto: true,
            pager: false,
            nav: true,
            speed: 600,
            maxwidth: 1920,
            namespace: "large-btns"
          });
    }

    head.js(
        "js/jquery.js",
        "js/fadetext.js",
        "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js",
        "css/slider/responsiveslides.min.js",
        initSliders     
    );  
</script>
```